Cryptomatte mask only applies to the first frame of the animation
Over the past week, I've been working on a project aimed at using Cryptomattes to overlay video footage onto moving screens. However, I’ve discovered an issue while compositing using Blender’s built-in compositor.
In the project, I want to overlay a piece of footage onto a phone screen. While the overlay works correctly on the first frame of the animation, it freezes and stays static for the rest of the animation, resulting in an odd effect.
Here is a snapshot of the project in Blender(before I render out the animation):

The object in the middle is a phone with a screen(a plane) parented onto it. The phone moves up during the first 3 seconds of the animation, and then down to its original position during the next three.
But when I render out an animation(144 frames) as an Exr multilayer image sequence(with Cryptomattes enabled), bring it into the Blender compositor(using the image sequence node), and attempt to lay the footage over the screen, it only applies to the first frame and not the others.
Here is a snapshot of my node setup in the compositor(after I've rendered out the animation):

Here is a video showing the result:
https://youtu.be/moiMN55yK4k
You can observe in the video above that it’s almost as if the footage sticks perfectly onto the phone’s screen in the first frame of the animation, but as the animation progresses it becomes clear that the phone is actually moving up and down the video footage rather than the video moving in sync with the phone.
How do I solve this?
Some more important things to note:

Though the animation is 6 seconds long, I wanted it to play over 30 seconds(in the compositor), so I turned on the ‘cyclic’ and ‘auto-refresh’ options on the image sequence node and the Cryptomatte node(in the compositor). I did this because it would make no sense to render out a 30-second looping animation when I could render a 6-second version of it and then just bring it into the compositor and loop it.

I also made the timeline, in the compositor, 30 seconds long. (630 frames at 24 frames per second)



The Cryptomatte only produces a mask in the shape of the phone. The phone moves, so does the mask shape. But moving a mask does not automatically move the footage with it, it is not parented to the mask in any way... I would rather create a phone with a screen showing the footage as a texture in scene, then it's moving with the phone.

Thanks for the answer @GordonBrinkmann! What did you mean by the last part though? Do you mean I render out the original animation with the footage itself applied as a texture?(Because that's something I'm trying to avoid as the render times would be way too long. I intend to reuse the animation over and over again with different footage.)  Or do you mean using the phone screen texture as a cryptomatte texture pass? (Because I've already tried this and it didn't work) Or did you mean use a completely different pass thst has nothing to do with cryotomattes?
